# Agent Expiry Auto notification send before 30 days Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and I want to create a stored procedure for below requirement.

Agent Expiring automated email notification sent by the system in case any agent is expiring
For Example
- Agent Code :EDSBOMDO code expires on 00DEC2018.
- before 30 days Agent expiry email notification sent to the Agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is not clear
but I'll assume those are custom data fields

I'd say you can do it via SQL Agent 
Run it daily and send out email for expiring AgentCode within 30 days

pseudo-code

```
SELECT agentEmail FROM table WHERE ExpiryDate < GETDATE()+30 
If @@ROWCOUNT > 1
  Email all these agents
```